# NSAutoLayout, View , Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-autolayout, autolayout

I am working on a client app, with a screen that has one top view ands a uitableview. I am new to iOS and NSAutoLayout, I used the recommended settings from xcode, and ended up with something that looks like this in interface builder 
[image: Interface Builder Screen shot]

But when I run this in simulator I get a weird space seperating the tableview and the top view, like this

[image: simulator screen shot]

Where is this space coming from ? how can I fix this?

update :

there is one constraint for the tblview, its basically that height = 500. could that be the issue? can I make that more dynamic? I am after all new and used whatever xcode recommended!

Comment: it should be something related to the top constraint of the top view, but i can not see your "Test" view in your views hierarchy in the storyboard

Comment: Test is a button inside the tblview , do you think that could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

coupe of things:

```
set leding, trailing n bottom pins for tbleview to 2.

set verticl spcing between tbleview nd custom view to 2.

set leding, trailing n top pins for custom view to 2.

set verticl spcing from custom view to bottom lyout to 548.
```

Screen shot:
[image: XIB]

then run on simultor:
[image]

hope it helps

Edit
Just select custom navigation view and add pins by selecting second menu option from available 3 options.

There will be a check mark "margin" just uncheck it. Select left right and bottom and add constraints.

It's really painful answering from iPhone dev typing

Comment: Hi, what is Sy tbleview TV, Custom View CV, SUperview SV?

Comment: thanks for this, but I really don;t know how to replicate the same constraints? do I drag and drop from tableview to view? can you give me more details? Thanks.

Comment: By default pins added between a superview and one view. For specifying pin between two custom views ctrl+drag works